# Are season rewards based on current rank or max rank achieved?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Are the rewards given to you at the end of the season based on what your current rank is when the season ends or what the highest rank you made in the season.

If I get to Diamond than become really bad and drop down to bronze, and I am bronze when the season ends, do I get rewards from Diamond or Bronze?

Are season rewards based on current rank or max rank achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The highest rank archieved counts!

> Players who participate in Hero League and Team League seasons will be
> rewarded with a practical pile of treasure at each season’s end based
> on their ranked performance in Team and Hero League. Ranked rewards
> will be granted based on the highest rank achieved during the season,
> including preseason.

Taken from the [official blog post](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/blog/20111014/ranked-play-revamp-5-6-2016) about the ranked play revamp.